How to access android files programmatically without ADB
I have made a Python script that will use ADB(Android Debug Bridge) to execute terminal commands on an android device connected by USB cable, and then use adb pull to copy individual files from the android to the windows PC.
I would like to make an application which can run on a PC and allow you to automatically copy all files on the phone (in certain folders recursively) which are not already in some folder on the PC to some destination folder on the PC. It should be possible to make this with ADB, but that requires all users having enabled developer options on the phone.
The question: Is it possible to programatically get info about and copy files from android to a PC over usb without using ADB? This would make the application I want to build a lot nicer, because the user would not have to enable developer options on their phone before using it.
Clearly windows file explorer has some method of this, because you can use that to view files. Does anyone know how windows file explorer works to explore android files?
Thank-you for any references or suggestions or context!

Use MTP. See OpenMtp for an implementation.
